# How can I read a header from an http request in golang?

Tags: go

If I receive a request of type `http.Request`, how can I read the value of a specific header? In this case I want to pull the value of a jwt token out of the request header.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the Docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Header)?

Comment: Yes, I have. I kept trying to use parenthesis instead of brackets, thanks.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use the [r.Header.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get):

```golang
func yourHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ua := r.Header.Get("User-Agent")
    ...
}
```

Comment: it return string array so not useful

Comment: It is useful if there are multiple values (multiple headers with the same name).

Comment: I wonder what makes you write `w`, `r` and `ua` instead of `responseWriter`, `request` and `userAgent`?

Comment: @DanielVartanov Its considered idiomatic in Go to use single letter variable names: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#variable-names, "Variable names in Go should be short rather than long. This is especially true for local variables with limited scope. Prefer c to lineCount. Prefer i to sliceIndex."

Comment: @MaxPRafferty oh no! Thanks for sharing though

Answer (score 22):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s %s %s \n", r.Method, r.URL, r.Proto)
    //Iterate over all header fields
    for k, v := range r.Header {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Header field %q, Value %q\n", k, v)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Host = %q\n", r.Host)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "RemoteAddr= %q\n", r.RemoteAddr)
    //Get value for a specified token
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n\nFinding value of \"Accept\" %q", r.Header["Accept"])
}
```

---

Connecting to http://localhost:8000/ from a browser will print the output in the browser.

Answer (score 12):

*Note: The accepted answer is missing some information.*

A Header represents the key-value pairs in an HTTP header.
It's defined as a map where key is of string type and value is an array of string type.

```
type Header map[string][]string
```

Actually, [r.Header.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get) gets the first value associated with the given key i.e. it just gets the first string from index 0.

This is okay if your header just have one value but if it has multiple values, you may miss out on some information.

**Eg**. User-Agent header has multiple values against the same key.

```
user-agent: ["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6)",  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36",]
```

So if you use `r.Header.get("User-Agent")` , it'll return `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6)` **only** and not the rest of the values.

If you want to get all the values you can use this:

```
req.Header["User-Agent"]
```